# How to grant Accessibilty access in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, accessibility

I'm struggling to get Accessibility permission in Xcode.

I have the following (working) code:

```
 func checkAccess() -> Bool{
    //get the value for accesibility
    let checkOptPrompt = kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt.takeUnretainedValue() as NSString
    //set the options: false means it wont ask
    //true means it will popup and ask
    let options = [checkOptPrompt: true]
    //translate into boolean value
    let accessEnabled = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions(options as CFDictionary?)

    if accessEnabled == true {
        print("Access Granted")
        label.stringValue = "Access Granted"
    } else {
        print("Access not allowed")
        label.placeholderString = "Access not allowed"
        label.stringValue = "Access not allowed"
    }

    return accessEnabled
}
```

When building and running the app in Xcode, AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions return false and I see the warning message appearing. When putting Xcode in the trusted apps, nothing changes. However, if I archive the app, I can run the archived .app and put the application into the trusted apps and AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions returns true.

So. how can I get the permission granted from Xcode?

Comment: okay I just realized that AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions also triggers to put the actual build in the trusted apps list and then I only need to check the checkmark to have accessibility access. You only have to erase the old build out of the list before compiling and running the new build.It's a bit tedious but better than creating a new archive every time.

Comment: "erase the old build out of the list before compiling and running the new build" how to do that?

Comment: In the menu bar, go to Product->Clean Build Folder

Comment: LOL this doesn't help  what really help is to compile app in RELEASE mode, after that it appears in Accessibility list, so may be allowed, and then can be used in DEBUG mode for development purposes