# How can I get AXUIElement if its role is AXWebArea

Tags: ios, swift, appkit

I encountered a strange problem.

I used AXUIElement to get the focusedUIElement in Google, and it worked well. But when I ran the same code again the next day, it didn't work.

After comparison, I remembered that I launched the Accessibility Inspector last time, but not this time. So I launched it, and then the code worked again.

For this reason, I recursively queried each child element and found that if I hadn't launched Accessibility Inspector, there was no element whose role was AXWebArea returned in the child elements.

The issue where the code stops working only occurs after restarting the Mac, not when exiting the Accessibility Inspector.

Has anyone encountered this problem?

The information about my Mac is as follows:
MacBook Air (Apple M1)
macOS 14.0
Xcode 15.0.1

Comment: Can you post some example code that exhibits your issue?

Comment: Here's some simple code:
    ```swift
    let systemPtr = AXUIElementCreateSystemWide()  
    var timer: Timer?  
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {  
            // TODO: Requesting Accessibility permissions  
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in  
                self.findFocusElement()  
            }  
    }  
    ```

Comment: ```swift
func findFocusElement() {
    if let focusedElement = systemPtr.getValue(.focusedUIElement) {
        let element = focusedElement as! AXUIElement
        let role = element.getValue(.role) as? String ?? ""
        debugPrint(role)
    } else {
        debugPrint("no find")
    }
}
```

Comment: ```swift  
extension AXUIElement {  

    func getValue(_ attribute: NSAccessibility.Attribute) -> AnyObject? {
        var value: AnyObject?
        let result = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(self, attribute.rawValue as CFString, &value)
        guard result == .success else { 
            return nil
        }
        return value
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to format code in comments.  
The comment above is about using a timer to obtain the focused element.  
And then the recursive code is in the following comment.  
@soundflix

Comment: ```swift
func getChildFocusElement(_ element: AXUIElement) -> AXUIElement? {
    if let childrenPtr = element.getValue(.children) as? [AXUIElement] {
        for child in childrenPtr {
            if let focused = child.getValue(.focused) as? Bool,
                focused {
                return child
            } else {
                if let childElement = getChildFocusElement(child) {
                    return childElement
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: You can't do that in comments. It would be better to [edit] and post your example code in the question.

Comment: You definitely have to ask for accessibility permissions. Your code works here after I call `AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions` like it's done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59147944/how-to-provide-accessibility-permissions-to-swift-apps-in-development)